Unable to display Tello Drone footage in React Native Expo App
I am currently working on a project where I am trying to stream video from a Tello drone to a mobile application built with React Native and Expo where I have done an EAS Build on for my app on my phone. I am using the react-native-vlc-media-player library to handle the video streaming.
Here is the relevant code from my DroneScreen.js file:
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  Animated,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native";
import dgram from "react-native-udp";
import KText from "../components/KText";
import { VLCPlayer } from "react-native-vlc-media-player";
import _ from "lodash";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5";

const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;

export default function DroneScreen() {
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false);
  const [isStreaming, setIsStreaming] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isInitialScreen, setIsInitialScreen] = useState(true);
  const [fadeAnim] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

  const clientRef = useRef(null);
  const serverRef = useRef(null);
  const videoServerRef = useRef(null);
  const playerRef = useRef(null);

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      fadeAnim.setValue(0);

      Animated.timing(fadeAnim, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 300,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
    }, [])
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    clientRef.current = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
    serverRef.current = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
    videoServerRef.current = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

    try {
      clientRef.current.bind(8889);
      serverRef.current.bind(8890);
      videoServerRef.current.bind(11111);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Failed to bind socket", err);
      return;
    }

    let timeoutId = null;
    let intervalId = null;

    let state = null;
    let rinfo = null;

    serverRef.current.on("message", (msg, rinfo) => {
      state = parseState(msg.toString());
      rinfo = rinfo;
      setIsConnected(true);
    });

    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (state && rinfo) {
        console.log(`server got: ${state} from ${rinfo.address}:${rinfo.port}`);
      }
    }, 15000);

    videoServerRef.current.on("message", (msg, rinfo) => {
      setIsStreaming(true);
    });

    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsConnected(false);
    }, 5000);

    return () => {
      clientRef.current.close();
      serverRef.current.close();
      videoServerRef.current.close();

      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, []);

  function parseState(state) {
    return state
      .split(";")
      .map((x) => x.split(":"))
      .reduce((data, [key, value]) => {
        data[key] = value;
        return data;
      }, {});
  }

  const sendCommand = (command) => {
    clientRef.current.send(
      command,
      0,
      command.length,
      8889,
      "192.168.10.1",
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error("Failed to send command", err);
          setIsConnected(false);
        } else {
          console.log("Command sent: " + command);
        }
      }
    );
  };

  const connectAndStartStreaming = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    sendCommand("command");
    setTimeout(() => {
      sendCommand("streamon");
      setIsInitialScreen(false);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 5000);
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
      {isInitialScreen || !isConnected ? (
        <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
          <Animated.Image
            source={require("../assets/tello-img.png")}
            style={{
              width: screenWidth * 1.3,
              resizeMode: "contain",
              position: "absolute",
              opacity: fadeAnim,
            }}
          />
          <View style={styles.greyContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[
                styles.connectButton,
                { bottom: 120, flexDirection: "row" },
              ]}
              onPress={connectAndStartStreaming}
              disabled={isLoading}
            >
              {isLoading ? (
                <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#fff" />
              ) : (
                <>
                  <Icon name="link" size={20} color="#fff" />
                  <KText style={styles.connectButtonText}>Connect</KText>
                </>
              )}
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <>
          {isStreaming &&
            (console.log("isStreaming:", isStreaming),
            (
              <VLCPlayer
                style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                source={{ uri: "udp://@0.0.0.0:11111" }}
                autoplay={false}
                initOptions={["--network-caching=150", "--rtsp-tcp"]}
                onError={(e) => {
                  console.log("onError", e);
                  setIsConnected(false);
                  setIsStreaming(false);
                }}
                onOpen={(e) => {
                  console.log("onOpen", e);
                  if (
                    playerRef.current &&
                    typeof playerRef.current.play === "function"
                  ) {
                    playerRef.current.play();
                  }
                }}
                onBuffering={(e) => {
                  console.log("onBuffering", e);
                  if (
                    e.bufferRate > 0 &&
                    playerRef.current &&
                    typeof playerRef.current.play === "function"
                  ) {
                    playerRef.current.play();
                  }
                }}
                onPlaying={(e) => console.log("onPlaying", e)}
                ref={playerRef}
              />
            ))}
          <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.buttonContainer}
              onPress={() => sendCommand("takeoff")}
            >
              <KText style={styles.buttonText}>Take Off</KText>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.buttonContainer}
              onPress={() => sendCommand("land")}
            >
              <KText style={styles.buttonText}>Land</KText>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.buttonContainer}
              onPress={() => sendCommand("streamoff")}
            >
              <KText style={styles.buttonText}>Off Stream</KText>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </>
      )}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

....

The problem I am facing is that I am not receiving the video stream from the drone on my mobile app. I have confirmed that my phone is connected to the drone via WiFi and the drone is configured to send the video stream to port 11111. I am able to connect and send commands like "takeoff" which work. The isStreaming state variable is being set to true which suggests the "streamon" command is working.
I have tried various solutions, including binding the socket to port 11111, but this doesn't seem to work and most solutions online tailor to Python. I have also checked the console logs for any errors or warnings, but there are none that seem to be related to this issue. The official Tello app on my phone is able to display the video.
I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!
